# Magento 2 - How to disable a plugin

Tags: overrides, plugin, di

## Problem:

I am using the extension **Fooman_PdfCustomiser**.

I need to disable the plugin named `fooman_pdfcustomiser_paymentinfoblock`.

**vendor/fooman/pdfcustomiser-implementation-m2/src/etc/di.xml**:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    ...

    <type name="Magento\Payment\Block\Info">
        <plugin name="fooman_pdfcustomiser_paymentinfoblock"
                type="\Fooman\PdfCustomiser\Plugin\PaymentInfoBlockPlugin"/>
    </type>

    ...
</config>
```

## Attempt:

I try to disable the extension from my own module **Company_App**.

**app/code/Company/App/etc/di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Payment\Block\Info">
        <plugin name="fooman_pdfcustomiser_paymentinfoblock"
                disabled="true"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/App/etc/module.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Base" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Fooman_PdfCustomiser"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Then I executed

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

## Result:

But it does not work. The original plugin is still loading.

## Update:

**Solved**: It was my fault. The extension **Company_App** was disabled, thats why the plugin deactivation was ignored.

Comment: I think di compile is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault. The extension **Company_App** was disabled, thats why the plugin deactivation was ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing plugin class in di.xml file
update your di.xml file by below code.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\Payment\Block\Info">
    <plugin name="fooman_pdfcustomiser_paymentinfoblock"
            type="\Fooman\PdfCustomiser\Plugin\PaymentInfoBlockPlugin"
    disabled = "true"/>
</type>
```

[Reference Link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: you have to remove "generated" folder from your route dir by using command (sudo rm -rf generated/) in linux

Comment: It does not work too.